# Upper bound of function .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods, upper-lower-bounds

Given a function $b(t,x), x\in \mathbb{R}^d, t \in[0,T]$, we can define
$$
b_n(t,x) = \frac{1}{1 + n^{-a} \left | b(t,x) \right | }b(t,x) 
$$
and we can see that $ \left | b_n(t,x) \right | \leq \min(n^a, \left | b(t,x) \right |) $ , meaning that $$
\left | b_n(t,x) \right | \leq n^a , \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d, t \in[0,T] .
$$

If we now define $$g(t,x) = b(t,x) + f(x)\; $$  and $$\;g_n(t,x) = b_n(t,x) + f(x), $$  where $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d \;$, is there any way we can find a simillar bound for $g_n(t,x)$? I can't seem to find any way to bound it since $f(x)$ has at most linear growth ( from Lipschitz continuity ). The only thing I managed to come up with is
$$
\left | g_n(t,x) \right | \leq n^a \left | b(t,x) \right |
                              + n^a\left | f(x) \right |
                              +\left | b(t,x) \right |\left| f(x) \right |
$$
or
$$
\left | g_n(t,x) \right | \leq  n^a \left | b(t,x) \right |\left| f(x) \right| \left(\ \frac{1}{n^a}+\frac{1}{\left | b(t,x) \right |}+\frac{1}{\left| f(x) \right|} \right).
$$
Note:

$b(t,x)$ is one-sided Lipschitz and has superlinear growth, $a \in (0,1/2]$.

Comment: I think you have to give more restrictions on $f$, or there is no uniform upper bound of $g_n(t, x)$ for $\forall x$. Just consider $f(x) = x$ which goes to infinity when $x\to\infty$, so $g_n(t, x)$ has no upper bound.

Comment: @zieac Yeah I figured as much. But in the end it doesn't matter so much, because I am dealing with random variables with bounded p-moments so it all works out. Thank you nevertheless.